# Provide summaries for questions

Tags: feature-request

There are a lot of questions with accepted answers that could be summarized in a few words, and answered in a few characters.

Wouldn't it make sense to have a "Summary" at the top of the question providing a "TL;DR" of both the question and the accepted answer?

Eg for [Is there a way to collapse all code blocks in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726525/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-code-blocks-in-eclipse) would be summarized as:

> Is there a way to collapse all code blocks in Eclipse?
>
> Yes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd>

The Summary field could be editable by the original author and the one who provided the accepted answer, for example.

Comment: You think that a three sentence answer is so long as to require a summary?  If either the question or an answer feels a short summary is merited, they can add one to their post.

Comment: Yes, especially for questions which have a clear answer, I'd rather have it formulated as a single line. Another benefit is that you would predictably get the answer right from the search engine excerpt.

Comment: I think that question had a very clear answer. You need just read the first sentence.. come on man.. this has to be a new level of lazy if you can't be assed to spend 30 seconds reading an answer.

Comment: and what about answers that aren't exactly summarizable? (e.g an answer with steps)

Comment: Then don't provide a Summary for that question. I don't mean for it to be mandatory, but a nice-to-have when the full page could be replaced by a single sentence. Also as developers since when is optimizing a 30s long process that happens thousands of times a day a bad thing?

Answer (score 12):

It's a nice idea in theory, but its usefulness here on Stack Overflow is extremely debatable. The Q&A format already encourages brief, succinct answers - how much added value would a summary really provide, given that if you really want to *use* an answer, you usually have to read it whole anyway?

Also, it's a practical impossibility. Stack Overflow has seven million questions, and it's an ongoing battle for some of them to even have good *titles*. Who would be writing the summaries, and who would be quality-controlling them?

Comment: Yes exactly. Not only is the utility debatable, implementation would be a nightmare.

Comment: But how many questions have an accepted answer and a significant number of pageviews? Note that I am not saying the summary should be mandatory.

Comment: @Master but a good answer is typically so succinct that a summary shouldn't really be necessary. We're not a repository of academic texts here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 exactly. The best answers, I often find, are succinct enough that a quick glance gives me the answer I need, and if it does go on longer, I find that's often additional useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Often Answers are already short, and an Answer often can't be summarised because an answer is only obtained by reading the Answer in its entirety.

1. So are we selective towards which Questions to add a summary to?
2. If yes, what criteria and who/group decides *when* to add one?
3. Or do we just put a summary on all of them - sometimes then pointlessly and so a waste of community time, reading, site resources, etc.
4. Either way, who maintains the summary when the Answer or Question changes (from edits etc)? A Question change could alter which is the better Answer  to use for a summary.
5. Do we update the summary to reflect when tech/code becomes depreciated?
6. Who's Answer do we choose to put in the summary?  Who decides which one is best?
7. When do we apply or propose a summary? When there is an accepted Answer? When there are 2 or more Answers to choose a summary from?...
8. Often, multiple Answers provide for different approaches, and more than one Answer can answer the question in a different way. Which do we use for the summary?
9. How do we determine or propose a block of text from an Answer for a summary?

---

Most of this can be attempted to be managed with community voting, but that brings a lot of considerations and potential issues/pit falls.
To be honest, I'm not convinced this could be done to a decent standard with community voting.

10. Can we propose more than one Answer for a Question's summary?
11. If yes to 10., what happens when the "*Summary Review Queue*" has multiple proposals for the same Question? Vote for your "favourite"? Sounds, iffy...
12. Reviews are prone to robo-review and actions taken from bad decisions, showing us community can be untrustworthy to make sane decisions. So deciding on which Answer to use as a summary, and what text to use from the Answer, could be a complete nightmare from the multitude of opinions and ideals.
    Votes based on thoughts such as: "I want this one" - "No this one is better" - "I agree this answer is the better one but with this bit of text as well/instead".
13. Do we remove voting rights from the questioner and answerers on the Question as they are biased?
14. Can summaries be edited?
15. Can summaries be voted up/down? Sounds "odd" right? But why not? Or should the vote be mirrored from the Answer the summary is taken from?

---

I'm just touching the tip of the iceberg, and while I don't want to just sound negative, unfortunately your proposal has all of these considerations and many more.

In essence, the idea is *really* good, and I agree that sometimes a basic sentence at the top would be very useful, but in practice I just don't think this would work on Stack.

It would be better (although still hard) to encourage users who are already answering to provide a TL;DR when possible.